# Executing ST_WITHIN using stored procedure in documentdb

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get a count for my location inside a polygon. Here is my stored proc:

```
function count(poly) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var query = {query: 'Select f.id from f WHERE ST_WITHIN(f.location, @poly)',
            parameters: [{name: '@poly', value: poly}]};

var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    query,
    function (err, docs, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!docs || !docs.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
        else getContext().getResponse().setBody(docs.length);
    });

if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');}
```

When I execute the same query in query explorer, I get the results, but through stored procedures, its returning "no docs found". It is returning the results for simpler queries but for that too, the max count returned is always 100. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I tried using ST_DISTANCE for these coordinates. It did returned count as 100(max value), but is not at all working for ST_WITHIN.

Edit:
It was not working.So I tried [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/Count.js) as described in the official example for counting the results. And voila!! It worked. So I moved to the next step to count all the locations in all the polygons I had as locally, there were too many round trips to get the count for each polygon. But calling the same function from a loop does'nt return anything. I have already tested each query of the array in documentdb studio and it does return results. Please help!!! The code for new procedure is:

```
function countABC(filterQueryArray) {

var results = [];
for (i = 0; i < filterQueryArray.length; i++) {
    countnew(filterQueryArray[i].QueryString, "");

}
getContext().getResponse().setBody(results);

function countnew(filterQuery, continuationToken) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var maxResult = 50000;
    var result = 0;

    tryQuery(continuationToken);
    function tryQuery(nextContinuationToken) {
        var responseOptions = {
            continuation: nextContinuationToken,
            pageSize: maxResult
        };

        if (result >= maxResult || !query(responseOptions)) {
            setBody(nextContinuationToken);
        }
    }

    function query(responseOptions) {
        return (filterQuery && filterQuery.length) ?
            collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, responseOptions, onReadDocuments) :
            collection.readDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), responseOptions, onReadDocuments);
    }

    function onReadDocuments(err, docFeed, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            throw 'Error while reading document: ' + err;
        }

        result += docFeed.length;

        if (responseOptions.continuation) {
            tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
        } else {
            setBody(null);
        }
    }


    function setBody(continuationToken) {
        var body = {
            count: result,
            continuationToken: continuationToken
        };            
        results.push(body);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show `poly`?

Comment: {'coordinates':[[[-72.56244522109489,42.195626800619728],[-72.5503062656826,42.195626160743714],[-72.550316627691416,42.186632945589423],[-72.562453856102479,42.186633585263621],[-72.56244522109489,42.195626800619728]]],'type':'Polygon'}

Comment: Have you tried it without the parameters abstraction? I'm wondering if it's an escaping issue with the @poly substitution?

Comment: Yes. I tried with full query as well. For ST_Distance, the same parameter is working.

Comment: Added to the question. I am not able to understand why no count is being set in the body which is being pushed to the results array

Comment: In an async environment like this, you shouldn't use a loop because you need to wait until the first querie(s) return before making new ones. You can sometimes get away with a batch at a time, just not too big a batch (5-10 in my experience). A common pattern is to build a list of all the queries that need to be done and pop values off that list when the prior query finishes. In your `onReadDocuments()` function.

Comment: filterQueryArray is the list of all the queries for which we need count. When called from .Net, if we pass them one by one, it takes around 4-5 minutes for around 100 polygons. That's why I tried to execute at serverside.But not sure how to handle this array. Can you please share some code snnipet or link from wher I can understand better how to handle this query list in ASYNC ENVIRONMENT in the stored procedure.

Comment: It's not clear whether ST_WITHIN is working or not with new sproc, if not, please provide the value f.location from one of documents that should match the within.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a isolated repro, such as VS solution (C#) that creates some docs and calls the sproc.

Answer (score 0):

With new sproc, it's not helpful to set result after the loop because at that time no queries are executed (results array will be empty). The idea is that all CRUD/query calls are queued and are executed after the script that queued them is finished (in this case main script).

Setting result/body needs to be done from callback. This is partially done already, but there is an issue that for every call of countnew, the "result" variable is reset to 0. Essentially, "var result = 0" needs to be done in main script.

Also, it's not recommended to use loops like the "for" loop when it calls  CRUD/queries in a loop without waiting for previous CRUD/query to finish (due to async nature), otherwise checking for isAccepted is not reliable. What's recommended it to serialize this loop, something like this:

```js
var result = 0;
step();

function step() {
  if (filterQueryArray.length == 0) setBody(null);
  else {
    var query = filterQueryArray.shift();
  
    // process current query. In the end (from callback), call step() again.
  }
}
```

Does this make sense?